# Why does my function keeps adding DOM nodes?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm developing a grid that accepts inputs from the user to change the number of inner elements

```
<section id="content">
        <div id="mother"></div>
</section>
```

The Javascript:

```
 const mother = document.querySelector("#mother");
 let squareside = 16;

function createGrid(squareSide){
            mother.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${squareSide}, 1fr)`;
            mother.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${squareSide}, 1fr)`;
            let squared = squareSide**2
            for (i = 0; i < squared; i++){
                const box = document.createElement("div");
                box.classList.add("default");
                box.addEventListener("mouseenter", changeColor);
                box.style.backgroundColor = "whitesmoke";
                mother.appendChild(box);
            }
        }


function resizer(){ //here is the problem:
            squareSide = prompt("How many squares per side on your grid?", "16");
            createGrid(squareSide);
            reseter();
        }
```

when I run the resizer function the DOM ADDS nodes to the original grid. the original has 256 elements, if I call resizer with the value of 10, it adds 100 more elements, instead of creating a new grid with just 100 nodes.

[This is part of the Odin project curriculum](https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/web-development-101/lessons/etch-a-sketch-project?ref=lnav)

Comment: You are just appending new nodes to #mother `mother.appendChild(box)`. If you want to start a new grid I guess you'd have to remove the previous elements first.

Comment: `resizer()` calls `createGrid()` with the prompt input. `createGrid()` then loops that many times and adds that many new `div` elements. The more you call `resizer()`, the more `div` elements you'll get. Perhaps you meant to have `createGrid()` wipe out the old grid before making a new one?

Comment: hey @subarachnid, thanks! That was it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus that was it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

After suggestions I added a couple of lines to remove the previous elements in a loop:

```
function resizer(){
            squareSide = prompt("How many squares per side on your grid?", "16");
            while(mother.hasChildNodes()){ //loops thru the parent div
                mother.removeChild(mother.firstChild); //removes the first child
            }
            createGrid(squareSide);
            reseter(); // just changes the coloring inside the grid
        }
```